# Distribution of things on one row.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

What is the meaning 4|5  4|3  2|1

I think it (4 boys x (2 girls x 3 boys) x (4 boys x(2 girl ...
I wish that I understand so well and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The picture is supposed to help us count the number of ways one can have a boy at the left end.

There are $4$ ways to choose that boy. For each such choice, there are $5$ ways to choose the next person, then $4$ ways to choose the next, then $3$ ways to choose the next, and so on, for a total of $(4)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)=480$.

Similarly, there are $(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)=720$ ways to arrange $6$ people in a row, with no restriction. That is how the book got the probability that a boy is at the left end is $\frac{480}{720}$.

**Remark:** Note that there is an easier way to solve the probability problem. For the person on the left is equally likely to be any of the $6$ people. Since there are $4$ boys, the probability it is a boy is $\frac{4}{6}$.

Comment: (4 boys x(3 boys+2 girls))...

Comment: Yes, the $5$ is $3+2$, but after we have chosen a boy for the left end,  sex distinctions are irrelevant for the remaining choices, and it is better to think in terms of people.